# Error while trying to run script in Xcode for firebase crash reporting

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I am trying to integrate the crash reporting of firebase in my project. Though I am successfully getting the crash report in the firebase console I seem to get these 3 errors:

> /Users/human/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DummyProject-cousedziotoermfdyvgdmbmchdta/Build/Intermediates/DummyProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/DummyProject.build/Script-45E477EF1D33D4631052B160.sh:
>   line 3: /Users/human/DummyProject/ServiceAccount.json:
>   Permission denied
>
> cat: : No such file or directory
>
> Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code
>   to indicate failure

How do I resolve these errors?

I followed these instructions [in firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios)

Comment: Could you confirm that the ServiceAccount.json file is readable by other processes on your system?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

1. **Replace** the Run Script build phase you added in Step 3b of [the instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#upload_symbol_files) with the simplified:

   ```
   "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym
   ```

   In short, delete everything but the last line. This will put **upload-sym** in interactive mode. If you did not use Cocoapods to install FirebaseCrash, use the full path to the **upload-sym** script where you installed the framework.
2. Delete any cached credentials you may have accidentally added:

   ```
   /bin/rm -f $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload.plist
   /bin/rm -f $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUploadToken.plist
   ```
3. Do a build. When the Run Script build phase starts, you will be prompted with a dialog for the location of the JSON credential file you downloaded in Step 1 of [the instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#upload_symbol_files). You will only be prompted once. Future builds will have the information in the credential cache. If you have permission problems, make sure you have the right JSON file and repeat step 2 above.

Comment: Also, make sure that **upload-sym** is executable. Cocoapods should honor the executable flag, but it may have been unset somewhere along the line.

Comment: This answer was correct for me for a while, now my build is freezing on "Running 4 of 4 custom shell scripts". I tried running all of the commands again, and making sure the upload-sym was executable. It seems to work when I have "Run Script Only When Installing" checked, but that would mean the symbols don't get uploaded on crashes, right? Do I just need to generate a new key?

Comment: I have also issue while set the run script, so i have checked the "Run the script only when installing", after that my code works fine.. but there is one issue in "https://console.firebase.google.com" , it says that.. mannually upload the symbol file, but its not a right way, so till date i face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What is your "Debug Information Format" set to in your Xcode Build Options? If it’s set to only "DWARF" it will show this erros during build. You could set to "DWARF with dSYM File" errors should disappear.